# WPF, No-touch deployment and error " [Application] encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience"

Tags: wpf, web-deployment-project

I have a problem and don't know what should I do.

We are deploying our application written in .NET 3.5 WPF using No-touch deployment. Our server is also written in .net 3.5 using WCF. Lots of users use this application by installing the shortcuts on their desktop. However there is a problem in our of our client. Application is installed correct but however when she tries to open the application it does not load but instead the client sees the following error occurs:

> [Application] encountered a problem
>   and needs to close. We are sorry for
>   the inconvenience We don't know what
>   is the problem.

The client has WinXP OS, .NET 3.5 SP1 and administrative privileges.

Do you have any suggestions?